# Bazaar undoing pull from wrong location

Tags: dvcs, bazaar, pull

I've accidentally pulled to my local bazaar repo from a wrong location.
Fortunately my files have not been overwritten, as bazaar recognized the difference:

```
bzr: ERROR: These branches have diverged. Use the missing command to see how.  
Use the merge command to reconcile them.`
```

However the object packs have been pulled, and I suspect they may cause conflicts if I don't clean them up now.

[I saw that with git you can do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754564/undoing-a-pull-from-the-wrong-github-repository) via `git reset --hard HEAD^`.

[Bazaar doc](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/migration/en/survival/bzr-for-git-users.html) says there's only partial support for that. What is the proper way of resolving this mistake with bazaar? Is `bzr revert` enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you got a message:

```
bzr: ERROR: These branches have diverged. Use the missing command to see how.  
Use the merge command to reconcile them.
```

Then you don't have to do anything. Bazaar don't pull anything that will cause you problems.